# How to resolve version conflicts between packages?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a function to record voice and save it as a file. However, an error occurred when pub get to the pubspec.yaml file.

Because every version of flutter_audio_recorder depends on file ^5.0.4 and shared_preferences_windows >=2.0.0 depends on file ^6.0.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with shared_preferences_windows >=2.0.0.

And because shared_preferences 2.0.9 depends on shared_preferences_windows ^2.0.0 and no versions of shared_preferences match >2.0.9 <3.0.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with shared_preferences ^2.0.9.

So, because mirinae_gugu depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.9 and flutter_audio_recorder ^0.5.5, version solving failed.

> pub get failed (1; So, because mirinae_gugu depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.9 and flutter_audio_recorder ^0.5.5, version solving failed.)

The package I am using is below.

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.9
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  sizer: ^2.0.15

  get: 3.24.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  camera: ^0.9.2
  google_speech: ^2.0.1
  sound_stream: ^0.3.0

  flutter_animation_progress_bar: ^2.0.1
  noise_meter: ^3.0.2
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.2
  audioplayers: ^0.19.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  share: ^2.0.4
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+1
  flutter_audio_recorder: ^0.5.5
```

Even though I fixed the error between flutter_audio_recorder and shared_preferences, I still get the error between different packages.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Run flutter clean. Then

In pubspec.yaml give

```
audioplayers: any
```

Delete pubspec.lock. Then run flutter pub get and flutter run. It should work as expected

Comment: I tried the above method, but the same error occurs when I do pub get.

Comment: Give flutter audio recorder also any

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_audio_recorder2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_recorder2) instead. This is an exact clone of `flutter_audio_recorder` but it supports dart null-safety support.

```
flutter_audio_recorder2: ^0.0.2
```

---

**Not Recommended Solution** (using old flutter_audio_recorder package).

Below is the solution using `flutter_audio_recorder`. This is the opened pull request [#58 - Added sound null safety support](https://github.com/rmbrone/flutter_audio_recorder/pull/58). So you can use it like below

Change the `flutter_audio_recorder` dependencies like below

```
flutter_audio_recorder:
  git:
    url: git://github.com/fayeed/flutter_audio_recorder.git
    ref: sound-null-safety
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency override, suppose `some_package` and `another_package` depends on incompatible `url_launcher` version, you can resolve conflict this way:

```
dependencies:
  some_package:
  another_package:
dependency_overrides:
  url_launcher: '5.4.0'
```